# MariaDB do not store select all view

Tags: linux, windows, mariadb

im using views in mariadb. at the moment i'm on a windows server. if i save in windows an select *(all) view for a table. next time if i open the view it stays as an select *(all).

in linux(i tested ubuntu and centos) after saving the view it writes out an select for each table not for an an select * (all).

Example Image: [linux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDBXr.png)

linux:

```
select `abo_duration`.`dur_id` AS `dur_id`,`abo_duration`.`dur_name` AS `dur_name`,`abo_duration`.`dur_short` AS `dur_short`,`abo_duration`.`dur_order` AS `dur_order`,`abo_duration`.`asdadsfasdf` AS `asdadsfasdf`,`abo_duration`.`neu` AS `neu` from `abo_duration`
```

Example Image: [windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4UOy.png)

windows:

```
SELECT * from abo_duration
```

is this an config issue?

ty

Answer (score 0):

No.  Those are just two representations of the same thing.  The shorter form will (sooner or later) be converted to the longer form.  *Then* the processing will occur.

I can't be more specific without first understanding what you mean by "saving the view" and "writes out".

Comment: i added two images for trying to explain my problem.
they are two servers. replicated.
one is in ubuntu(linux) and one is in windows. 
look at the writeouts.


windows will leave the view as an select all. but linux does the select for column.

Comment: Are you doing `EXPLAIN SELECT ... ; SHOW WARNINGS;`?  That is the only way I know to _see_ the longer form.